# Dynamic Routes Rails 4, taken from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Frustrating, I can't find an eligible solution for my problem.

In my Rails 4 app, I want to give my users the possibility to add their own custom post types to their sites. Like:

```
www.example.com/houses/address-1
www.example2.com/sports/baseball
```

Both would work, but only for the linked sites. Sports and houses would be the (RESTful) post types, taken from the db, added by users.

I have been struggling to find a elegant solution to accomplish this. I found http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4 but that feels kinda hacky and I'm not sure if reloading the routes works in production, I'm getting signals that it won't.

I'd say I have to use routes constraints http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints but I don't have a clue how to approach this.

To be clear, I have no problem with the site setting stuff, the multi tenancy part of my app is fully functional (set in Middleware, so the current site is callable in the routes.rb file). My issue is with the (relative) routes, and how they could be dynamically set with db records.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Are you pointing multiple domains to one app?

Comment: Yes. It's a multi tenancy app, with the tenant (Site) based on the domain entered. The post type would be linked to the tenant (site_id field).

Answer (score 2):

I think route constraints don't work for you because your domain is a variable here. Instead, you should be examining the `request` object.

In your `ApplicationController`, you could define a method that would be called before any action, like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :identify_site

  def identify_site
    @site = Site.where(:domain => request.host).first
  end
end
```

As you scale, you could use Redis for your domains so you're not making an expensive SQL call on each request.

Then you can just add the `@site` as a parameter to whatever call you're making. I'm assuming you're doing some sort of "Post" thing, so I'll write some boilerplate code:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.where(:site => @site, :type => params[:type], :id => params[:id])
  end

end
```

Just write your routes like any other regular resource.

Comment: I have no problem with the Site setting stuff, I've done all that already. Guess I could've been clearer on that. Still, I dont know if your edit of the title to 'Domains' is right. It's not what I meant. Your solution would work I guess though, but I would have to check the post type in the controller actions at every request, whether the entered type exists for this site and so on. I'd say this could be done in the routes, hence my mentioning constraints. Thanks for your answer though, maybe I should work it your suggested angle. I'll put it here if I find a solution.

Comment: @KobusPost You should post some code, especially your current routes and maybe the relevant boiled down controller method, so your question is clearer.